# Change (reduce) Gnome 3 horizontal icon padding in notification area (Debian Wheezy)

Tags: gnome3, gui, debian, user-interface

I'm using Gnome 3.4 **classic mode** on Debian Wheezy.

In the notification area, I would like to know **how to change (reduce) the horizontal spacing (or padding) of the icons**.

By default, the icons are *very far from each other*, so I'm wasting much space on this bar.

[image: Adwaita theme - bad spacing]

I'm using the default theme "Adwaita", but please note that when I change this to the "HighContrast" (or "HighContrastInverse") theme, the icons *get close to each other*, which is what I want to achieve (but on the default theme):

[image: HighContrastInverse theme - good spacing]

I have been searching on the web and modifying a few .css files without success...

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu 18.04 (Gnome 3), the stylesheet is named `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`.

As jpoppe wrote, `.panel-button` > `natural-hpadding` must be adjusted. If the space is still too big for your taste, also reduce `minimum-hpadding`:

```css
.panel-button {
    -natural-hpadding: 12px;  /* change HERE */
    -minimum-hpadding: 6px;   /* and here */
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #eee;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    transition-duration: 100ms;
}
```

If you don't want to restart, you can also only reload the theme via

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'Main.loadTheme();'
```

---

**Edit:** In Ubuntu 20.04, the stylesheet is packed in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/gdm3-theme.gresource`.

List files

```
gresource list /usr/share/gnome-shell/gdm3-theme.gresource
```

Extract file

```
gresource extract /usr/share/gnome-shell/gdm3-theme.gresource /org/gnome/shell/theme/gdm3.css > gdm3.css
```

While it is possible to change the file and recompile it back into the `gresource` file, it is better to create a [child theme](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/) instead.

1. Create folder: `mkdir -p ~/.themes/NAME/gnome-shell`
2. Create manifest `theme.json` *(optional)*:

   ```
   {
     "shell-theme": {
       "name": "NAME",
       "author": "AUTHOR",
       "version": "0.0",
       "type":   "custom",
       "url": "URL"
      }
   }
   ```
3. Create style `gnome-shell.css`:

   ```
   #panel {
       font-size: 0.9em;
   }

   .panel-button {
       -natural-hpadding: 4px;
       -minimum-hpadding: 2px;
   }
   ```

   It should include the default CSS automatically. If this doesn't work, try to add one of the following lines to the beginning:

   ```
   @import url("resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/gdm3.css");
   @import url("/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css");
   ```
4. Select theme `NAME` with `gnome-tweak-tool` (*Tweaks > Appearance* > *Shell*)

Comment: MY HERO. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: you are the best

Answer (score 2):

Find the "natural-hpadding" line in (/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css) and replace 12 px with the value you like:

```
.panel-button {
    -natural-hpadding: 5px;
    -minimum-hpadding: 6px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ccc;
    transition-duration: 100ms;
}
```

For more information and tips see: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=86813 (section 2g)

Comment: Although this seems to work for Gnome *Shell*, it **does not work** when using the *Classic mode* (the mode I'm using).